# Can you run a standalone angularJS web application in backbase 5.5.1 (newest)?

Tags: angularjs, backbase-portal

We are developing a standalone angularJS web application and need to make it work in the newest backbase portal.

We have no idea if this is even possible?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Backbase widgets work standalone and follow the W3C specifications. However, if you are writing a SPA as a whole, you are not getting the true benefits of widgets.
You should separate your application into widgets, in other words, mini angular applications.